# ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',

Tags: node.js, express, testing, passport-facebook, passport-google-oauth

I am running some test on a mocked (facebook/google)strategy but the problem I have when run those test one by one it's running but when I run them simultaneously they are not working after the first test, the connection of the application fails immediately.

I tried to run in different describe but nothing has changed I am using nodejs and @passport-next/passport-mocked as a dependency to help me to mock those strategies.

```
  import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import passport from 'passport';
import '../config/passport';
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import server from '../index';

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const should = chai.should();

describe.only('login through facebook', () => {
  it('redirects to facebook', (done) => {
    chai
      .request(server)
      .get('/api/v1/users/auth/facebook')
      .end((_err, res) => {
        res.redirects[0].should.contain('api/v1/users/auth/facebook/callback?__mock_strategy_callback=true');
        done();
      });
  });
  it('redirects to google', (done) => {
    chai
      .request(server)
      .get('/api/v1/users/auth/google')
      .end((_err, res) => {
          console.log(_err);
        // res.redirects[0].should.contain('api/v1/users/auth/google/callback?__mock_strategy_callback=true');
        done();
      });
  });


});
```

this is my test file

```
import passport from 'passport';
import config from './auth';


let FacebookStrategy;
let GooglePlusStrategy;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook');
  GooglePlusStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20');
} else {
  FacebookStrategy = require('passport-mocked').Strategy;
  GooglePlusStrategy = require('passport-mocked').OAuth2Strategy;
}

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  name: 'facebook',
  clientID: '2618632188182397',
  clientSecret: 'f8a48d72223691ad05ca936fa20049e9',
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/auth/facebook/callback',
  profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  const firstName = profile._json.firstName;
  const lastName = profile._json.last_name;
  const email = profile.emails[0].value;
  const user = { firstName, lastName, email };
  // console.log(profile);
  done(null, user);
}));


passport.use(new GooglePlusStrategy({
  name: 'google',
  clientID: config.google.clientID,
  clientSecret: config.google.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/auth/google/callback'
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
  const user = {
    username: profile.displayName,
    email: profile.emails[0].value,
    isverified: true
  };
  console.log(profile);
  cb(null, user);
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

export default passport;
```

this is my passport configuration

```
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(`Listening on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

this is my app index

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email'] }));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req,res) => res.send(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"));


app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email', 'profile'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google'), (req,res) => res.send(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>") );
```

these are my routes

I expect the result of my test to in format of ***json*** but right now when I run the result in ***null*** and I git error

```
Listening on port 3000
  login through facebook
    ✓ redirects to facebook (57ms)
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3000,
  response: undefined }
    ✓ redirects to google
```

the error I am getting

Answer (score 0):

you need *some* part of the application to handle the callback (ie: you need to expose http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/auth/facebook/callback and http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/auth/google/callback, and ideally make them ).

According to the error, Facebook can't reach that point...

Please apply a similar solution to the section "Routes" from that [Passport site link](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/).

```
// GET /auth/google/callback
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
//   request.  If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
//   login page.  Otherwise, the primary route function function will be called,
//   which, in this example, will redirect the user to the home page.
app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Comment: not really because when I run one test alone it runs perfectly but the problem comes when I run them both, one has to fail

Comment: what do you mean ? how does it fail ?

Comment: When one test passes then test after it will fail and shows about not being able to connect to the application address

Comment: no there is no 500 code it just stops there any way I used another way because this wasn't working